# I am trying to update the state using the React useState hook?? The Create Read and Delete part has been done but iam not able to update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am making a To Do App using useState react hook. 
I have complete with Create Read and Delete parts but 
I have not been able to update the state. 
Can somebody please help me. 
I have complete the same with Class component.

/****************************** MY app.js file ********************************************/

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import ToDoList from "./Components/ToDoList";

function App() {
  const [change, handleChange] = useState("");
  const [items, addItem] = useState([]);

  let handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(change)
    if (change !== "") {
      addItem([...items, { text: change, key: Date.now() }]);
      handleChange("");
    }
  };

  let removeTask = (key) => {
    let item = items.filter((ele) => {
      return ele.key !== key;
    });
    console.log(item);
    addItem([...item]);
  };

  let updateToDo = (value, key) => { // <<<<<<< I need to make changes in this piece of code.
    let allItem = items.map((e) => {
      if (e.key === key) {
        e.text = value;
      }
      console.log(...allItem);
      // addItem([...items, { allItem }]);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="toDoContainer">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
          value={change}
          placeholder="Add Item"
        />
        <button>Add Item</button>
      </form>
      <ToDoList items={items} removeTask={removeTask} updateToDo={updateToDo} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


/*************************************** My ToDoList.js *************************************/

import React from "react";
import "./ToDoList.css";

function ToDoList({ items, removeTask, updateToDo }) {
  let toDoItems = items.map((item) => {
    return (
      <div className="toDoItems" key={item.key}>
        <p>
          <input
            type="text"
            id = {item.key}
            value={item.text}
            onChange={(e) => updateToDo(e.target.value, item.key)}
          />

          <span onClick={() => removeTask(item.key)}>&#10008;</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  });
  return <div>{toDoItems}</div>;
}

export default ToDoList;
```

Comment: `// <<<<<<< I need to make changes in this piece of code.` And what changes do you need to make?

Comment: addItem([...items, { text: change, key: Date.now() }]); ==> addItem([...items, { text: e.target.value, key: Date.now() }]); . Try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map items into new array and when the item key matches the key parameter update the text property.

```
let updateToDo = (value, key) => {
  const allItem = items.map(item => {
    const newItem = {...item};
    if (item.key === key) {
      newItem.text = value;
    }
    return newItem;
  });
  console.log(...allItem);
  addItem(allItem);
};
```

Comment: Here is the git hub link for the project I would be very happy if you would take a look at it. The state updates but the behavior is very unlikely. 
The piece fo code you provided didnt work.
https://github.com/AbhiTsong/to-do-app

Comment: @AbhishekSubba Oops, you're quite right, I had a typo, it should be `newItem.text = value;` not `item.text = value;`. I updated answer. If there is still issue or this solution doesn't resolve your issue then it's easier if you can provide a codesandbox with reduced down code to just enough to reproduce your issue. Sometimes you'll find when you start breaking your code down to a minimal example the issue will become *very apparent*.

Answer (score 0):

buddy!

First fo all, I suggest you can read [document about React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), it have clear explain how to update State when you using `useState`, I split several parts below:

On here `const [items, addItem] = useState([]);`, The Hooks `useState` will return a array, the first item is your value of state, at this time is a empty array `[]`, the second item is a method which can update value of state.

Next, in your update method `updateToDo`, you used `map` to update original value of state and create the new value of state. so why didn't you call `addItem` to update your value of state?(Maybe you tried, but I have no idea for why you comment out that line?)

You just need to pass new value of state for `addItem`, and I suggest you can rename it to `setItem` instead of `addItem`.

You can following:

```js
let updateToDo = (value, key) => { // <<<<<<< I need to make changes in this piece of code.
  let allItem = items.map((e) => {
    if (e.key === key) {
      e.text = value;
    }
    addItem(allItem);
  });
};
```

Comment: Here is the git hub link for the project I would be very happy if you would take a look at it. The state updates but the behavior is very unlikely.
https://github.com/AbhiTsong/to-do-app